# Stopping looping sound in java

Tags: java

So I have a class to play sound and I have a option to loop it or play it once and a stop option but the stop option does not stop the looping here is the code to stop the sound:
EDIT added the whole thing
    package me.welsar55.story;

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Sound {

public static synchronized void clip(final String fileName, final String action) 
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    { 
        public void run() 
        {

            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("play"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.start();
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
                }
            }
            else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("loop"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
                }
            }
 else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
{
    try 
    {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.stop();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
    }
}
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code so we can see how it is started in the first place.  I'm sure opening the sound before you play it when it's already open is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`if` is a statement not a loop , I am not sure what you mean by not stopping looping

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error ? where is the code for looping ?. I think you might be creating a new stream to the file for closing. You might want to return the actual stream which is used for playing the file and close it. I cant confirm this without seeing the complete code

```
        public class Sound {

        private static Map<String,Clip> clipMap = new HashMap();

    public static synchronized void clip(final String fileName, final String action) 
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        { 
            public void run() 
            {

                if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("play"))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Clip clip = getClip(fileName);
                        clip.start();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
                    }
                }
                else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("loop"))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Clip clip = getClip(fileName);
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
                    }
                }
             else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    Clip clip = getClip(fileName);
                    clip.stop();
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("play sound error: " + e.getMessage() + " for " + fileName);
                }
            }
            }

            private Clip getClip(final String fileName)
                    throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException,
                    IOException {

                Clip clip = clipMap.get(fileName);
                if(clip == null)
                {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                clip.open(inputStream);
                clipMap.put(fileName, clip);
                }
                return clip;
            }
        }).start();
    }

    }
```

check if this works

Comment: I edited the code block if you can check it out now that would be nice

Comment: you need to call stop on the same clip which started playing. Here for starting the action you are using one clip and stopping you are creating another clip. You need to pass the same clip to this method to stop playing. Or else you can cache the object in Map and do that I will post the code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clip.stop(), try

```
if (clip.isOpen()) {
    clip.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```